# A memory leak using WPF ListBox and DataTable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, memory-leaks

I seem to be having a situation which is causing a memory leak.   As I run this code and watch the real-time diagnostics while clicking the "Do It" button, it appears as though my data tables are never being freed.  I don't understand what could be rooting this data.   Could anyone provide me any insight on why this is?  And what can be done about it?

**MainWindow.Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Do It" Margin="5 5 5 0" Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <ListBox Margin="5" Name="lister">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=", " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.Xaml.vb**

```
Imports System.Data

Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim tbl As New DataTable
        tbl.TableName = "Contacts"
        tbl.Columns.Add("LastName")
        tbl.Columns.Add("FirstName")
        For idx As Integer = 1 To 50000
            Dim row As DataRow = tbl.NewRow()
            row.Item("LastName") = $"Last {idx}"
            row.Item("FirstName") = $"First {idx}"
            tbl.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        lister.ItemsSource = tbl.AsDataView()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does it still leak if you `Dispose` the old datatable properly?

Comment: Just how big is the size of you 5000 data?

Comment: If you have 50000 results you may need a different system that searches or filters results, no-one want to scroll thru that may records.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, the data is still rooted even if i call .dispose on the table.  In fact, when I first ran across this, i wasn't using a DataTable at all ... I was just using an array of data objects.  Even those seemed to be rooted by the list box and unable to garbage collect.

Comment: @OneFineDay Thanks, but this isn't the point.  The point is it is a leak.  Something is rooting the data.  The same thing happens with 100 records as it does with 5000 ... i chose to demo 50k records so you can easily see the chunk of memory in the realtime diagnostics that never gets freed.